# Smart Contract NFT Issue

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft

i've been lately working on an NFT smart contract, to start with, i've use ERC721 Openzepellin contract as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/utils/Counters.sol";

 contract NAMZZ is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage{
 using Counters for Counters.Counter;

 Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
 uint256 MAX_SUPPLY = 5000;

 constructor() ERC721("NAMZZ", "NMZ") {}

 function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public{
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
    require(tokenId <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Sorry, all NFTs have been minted!");
    _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
}

// The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
    internal
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
}

function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
    super._burn(tokenId);
}

function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
    returns (string memory)
{
    return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
}

function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
    public
    view
    override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    returns (bool)
{
    return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}
}
```

Everything seems to work perfectly as i can mint NFTs and even use the SafeTransferFrom Method to move the NFTs from 1 address to another. After minting my first 2 NFTs, i linked my metamask account (the one used to mint the NFTs) to the Opensea Testnet and i was able to see my NFTs there in the collected tab but, after transfering 1 of the NFTs to another address, even if the smart contract shows that the NFT with ID 1 is owned by the second address, and even Opensea says the owner of the ID1 NFT is the 2nd address i used, there is no way i can see it again in the Collected Tab on Opensen.

As you can see on the screenshots, i've created 2 NFTs, i have just 1 Collected (the NFT with ID 0) while it should show 2 Collected since the NFT with ID 1 owner is "ME", still, i cannot see it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GM there!

There's nothing wrong with the contract, just OpenSea usually doesn't index NFT very well so it might take some delay (or never) to have your NFT appear in the collected tab.

However, you shouldn't worry since it's UI problem, as long as you go to Etherscan or Polygonscan, depending on where you NFT is deployed, and you have your NFT there, you own them and OpenSea has no power to take those NFT from you.

Cheers~

Comment: Oh i see, after almost 24 hours, still no updates, but is good to know that it is just their issue. Anyway, any other place where i could test my NFTs? Looking into testing the metadata file/format